# BIOS and Windows 7 only detect 4GB of RAm out of 8GB

Tags: windows-7, memory, motherboard, bios

I don't know for how long this has been going on, but my BIOS only detects 4GB (2x2GB) out of 8GB (total of 4x2GB). CPU-Z tells me I have 8GB of RAM installed and Windows tells me that I have 8GB (4GB usable). I have a 64-bit Windows 7 OS.

I've tried to take them out, dust them off and put them back in again.

SPECS:

- CPU: Intel Core i5 760
- MOTHERBOARD: ASUSTeK P7P55D-E PRO
- RAM: 4x2GB Corsair XMS3 DDR3
- GPU: AMD Radeon 280x

Edit: the problem solved itself out of nowhere

Comment: Forgot to add that I'm on 64-bit Windows 7

Comment: Check in the BIOS if you are running in single channel mode. Is your BIOS the latest?

Comment: According to CPU-Z, my BIOS is from 2012 so that's most likely a no

Comment: Your latest BIOS version is [Version 1703](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/P7P55DE_PRO/HelpDesk_Download/) from 2012/08/01. If this is indeed your version, you can still reset it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved itself. I installed java 64-bit and started technic launcher with 2.5GB RAM instead of one. When I exited the program, the screen flickered and it was back to normal

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Installing Java and running a game isn't going to make your BIOS start recognizing more memory.

Comment: I know. That's what happened though

Answer (score 0):

If the *only* place that the full RAM is not recognized is BIOS, is that [up-to-date?](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/P7P55DE_PRO/HelpDesk_BIOS/) Since the latest BIOS appears to be seven years old, though, that may not resolve the apparent issue.

Since you state Windows sees the full 8 GB (presumably in the *System* dialog), you might also check systeminfo.exe:

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `cmd` and select `cmd.exe`.
- Type `systeminfo` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This displays *Total Physical Memory* and *BIOS version*. You might also try [HWiNFO64](https://www.hwinfo.com/download/), portable or installed.

[image: HWiNFO64 memory display for Toshiba laptop]

You *could* [test the RAM with the Windows Memory Diagnostic utility](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/test-your-ram-with-windows-memory-diagnostic-tool/), but that requires a reboot and much time.

If the RAM is as expected, and all applications work as expected, then I'd assume this is a minor flaw in BIOS and ignore it. *If it ain't broke, don't fix it.*